# How to lock with ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, spring, locking

I would expect the following test to only print "has been locked" once.
BUT it consequently prints the line.

```
public class LocKTest {
    @Test
    public void testLock() {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        while (true) {
            if (lock.tryLock()) {
                //lock.lock(); same result if I include an explicit lock here
                System.out.println("has been locked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, `tryLock` will lock the `ReentrantLock` if possible (ie if not locked yet). But obviously this is not the case.

How can I set such a lock threadsafe?

Comment: It is in while loop and once lock is acquired, again same object is requesting for the same lock so it is getting lock every time and it will print `has been locked` forever.

Comment: that's why it is called reentrant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is `ReentrantLock`, meaning you can `re-enter` if you already own the lock.

If you wish to have the thread block, you could use for example a `Semaphore` with 1 (or more) permits.

Comment: So then I probably misunderstood the concept. Is there any `Lock` implementation that would suit my needs?

Comment: @membersound `Semaphore` would be the most straight-forward one I think. There's no non-reentrant Lock implementation available.

Comment: Semaphore with a single permit, re-entrancy doesn't mean its not Threadsafe. Also, when you are locking, do you have some condition to be met to go ahead. You can't just lock and do nothing

Comment: Thanks, `Semaphore` seems the best solution here. @NitinDandriyal of course the code is just an example to demonstrate my issue. In reality I'd of course have an action to execute, and not an endless loop.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at `Condition` which you can use as `Condition c = lock.newCondition()` and then you can invoke `c.await()` and `c.notify()` based on your action events (they work just like wait/notify inside synchronized block/method)

Answer (score 0):

To quote the documentation about [`tryLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()) (the emphasis in bold added by me):

> Acquires the lock if it is not held **by another thread** and returns immediately with the value true, setting the lock hold count to one

In this case, the current thread is holding the lock, so you ca reenter("re-acquire") it multiple times. If you were to run each iteration of the loop from a different thread, the first one would acquire the lock, and the second would fail to acquire it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [Kayamans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118881/3751577), you could implement your own `Lock` class:

```
public class Lock {

    private boolean isLocked = false;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        while(isLocked) {
            wait();
        }
        isLocked = true;
    }

    public synchronized void unlock() {
        isLocked = false;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
public class LocKTest {
    @Test
    public void testLock() {
        Lock lock = new Lock();
        while (true) {
            if (lock.lock()) {
                System.out.println("has been locked"); // prints only once
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code example taken from [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html).

Comment: True, but generally the `java.util.concurrent` package classes implement locking in a more efficient manner, avoiding `synchronized`.